# Reopen queue audits are very obvious

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits

In the reopen queue, questions are displayed with most of the influential information removed, usually giving you just the revision information.

[image: Example of a real reopen request]

In my case, I am given just the markdown changes, with no information about why it was closed and who it was closed by.

But in the case of a review audit, I'm given the original question with the notice of why it was closed, which includes who closed it. I don't have the option of viewing the markdown changes, and the vote count is displayed.

[image: Example of an obvious review audit]

It's a noticeable change that makes it *really obvious* that it is a review audit. I understand that audits are meant to stop robo-reviewers, and some people will surely still fail these audits, but shouldn't they look at least *somewhat like* a standard review?

Comment: I went ahead and added 300-some *non-edited* review tasks to the queue so you'd have a chance to observe more closely the match between these and audits...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways questions enter the reopen queue:

1. Someone votes to reopen a closed question
2. A question is closed that attracts some unusual number of votes / views / chickens
3. A question is closed and then edited

You're used to seeing reviews triggered by #3. They're fairly common, and *very* noticeable. But there are questions that'll come up for review that haven't been edited since being closed - [you reviewed one just the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6879703) - and when such questions come up they appear just like the audits.